# Will a Cloned Site Get Indexed Without Links to Inner Pages

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, google-index

I've cloned a site to a new domain just to use the functionality of the site. Everything will be different on the new domain, but there are a lot of left over files and you can access URLs that are identical to the original domain.

Can these URLs, on the new domain, get indexed in Google and cause duplicate content problems? Even if they cannot get indexed, is it best practice to delete them?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that if these links are not needed, that they be removed for safety sake.

However, you can always use canonical links to indicate that the original content is on your older site. Google gives guidance on this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en Look at this specifically: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#2 where a link can indicate that it is duplicate by placing a canonical link in the header:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://blog.example.com/dresses/green-dresses-are-awesome" />
```

This means that on your new domain you can add a canonical link within the header of the pages in question without an issue of duplicate content. Even if you do not link to these pages, this is another option that could be done to stay safe.

Comment: I thought it was necessary, when setting up cross-domain canonical links, to validate ownership of both domains in GWT. However, I can't find reference of this at the moment.

Comment: @w3d If you do find it, let us know. Otherwise, it would seem counter productive of Google to make that requirement since so few site owners use Google products at all. And let us not forget that Google is not the only search engine on the planet. Okay okay! They are the only one worth a hoot (I really wanted to say ****). But that is beside the point. MSN/Bing will never get it's act together. It has been over a decade now and it still stinks (I really wanted to say *****).